# Get PyCharm to know what classes are mixin for

Tags: python, django, ide, pycharm, mixins

Our application has set of complex form wizards. To avoid code duplication I created several mixins.

The problem is that PyCharm highlights mixin methods with `Unresolved attribute refference` error.
This is correct as `object` does not have such methods. But I know that this mixin will be used only with special classes. Is there any way to tell this info to PyCharm?

For now I use such approach:

```
class MyMixin(object):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        assert isinstance(self, (ClassToBeExtended, MyMixin))
        # super.get_context_data is still highlighter, 
        # as super is considered as object
        context = super(MyMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context.update(self.get_preview_context())
        return context

    def get_preview_context(self):
        # without this line PyCharm highlights the self.initial_data
        assert isinstance(self, (ClassToBeExtended, MyMixin))
        return {'needs': (self.initial_data['needs']
                          if 'type' not in self.initial_data
                          else '%(needs)s %(type)s' % self.initial_data)}
```

While this works for some cases like autocomplete for `self.`, it fails for other cases like `super`. Is there a better approach to achieve the desired behavior?

*P.S.: I know that I can disable reference check for specific name or whole class, but I don't want to do this as it will not help in typo checks and autocomplete.*

Comment: FWIW, if pycharm can't resolve the attribute references I suspect it also won't be able to neither check for typos nor autocomplete (since it has no reference to use)...

Comment: `get_context_data(self:ClassToBeExtended)` (python3 of course) seems working.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can [type-hint](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.1/type-hinting-in-pycharm.html) to PyCharm what kind of classes to expect.

```
class DictMixin(object):
    def megamethod(
        self,  # type: dict
        key
    ):
        return self.get(key)
```

It's still not quite comparable to other type handling.
PyCharm is lazy in evaluating it, and only does so when first working on `self`.
Things are a bit tricky when accessing attributes of the mixin as well - `self,  # type: dict | DictMixin` works for one of my classes, but not in my test code.
In [python 3.5](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0484/#stub-files), you should be able to use [`# type: typing.Union[dict, DictMixin]`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

Answer (score 2):

If you are creating Mixin, for, let's say ClassSub, which is subclass of ClassSuper, you can implement Mixins this way:

```
class Mixin1(ClassSuper):
    pass


class Mixin2(ClassSuper):
    pass
```

and then use them like:

```
class ClassSub(Mixin1, Mixin2):
    pass
```

That way I use some mixins for models in Django. Also, [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) uses similar pattern (gives models that are actually mixins). Basically, this way you don't have to inherit `ClassSuper`, because it's "included" in every of your mixins.

Most important - PyCharm works like a charm this way.