# Mixin class doesn't show "unresolved attribute reference" in core modules

Tags: python, syntax, pycharm

Have a look at **CheckURLMixin** class's **describe() method** in Django urls modules (Line number 107). It has name attribute (Line number 112) which is never assigned to the class. But there's no syntax highlighting.

[image]

Though the name is assigned in the child class (Line number 146).

When I do the same separately using the same logic Syntax highlighting detects it.

[image]

The point is I'm trying to write a mixin class for another class. But the syntax highlighting pops up there as well. I tried searching for the answer. Found some like [Get PyCharm to know what classes are mixin for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33956505/get-pycharm-to-know-what-classes-are-mixin-for/38398808) which does help. But the solutions violates this case. Why is it so ?